# Which one is more dangerous to human body among high voltage or current and their AC and DC versions?

Tags: voltage

I have already gone through many similar questions but none seems to quench my thirst to know.
Take the example two different sources A and B, as -

**A** = 1000 V & 1A

**B** = 1 V & 1000A

Note - Consider the given parameters that are fixed(constant) using circuits.

So which one is more lethal to the human body?
Looking to have a clear and crisp explanation.

Comment: Um you can't define both your voltage and your current. That's not how physics work. So, the problem B as stated in your question can't occur - unless your body is damn near superconducting. (and then you'd have other problems)

Comment: You don't get to pick what the human body is like, which is what you are doing.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I just try to give the sample or test circuits for comparison.
Can you help to clear this picture to me?

Comment: What @MarcusMüller means is, when you have a source with defined voltage and current, it usually means the source has a fixed voltage, but the current stated is MAXIMUM possible.   Consider if the outputs of your power supply aren't connected to anything.  In that case, current would be always be 'zero', right?    The maximum current is limited by the supply, but otherwise current is controlled by the resistance of the load.

Comment: You might ask Thomas Edison whether AC or DC is more dangerous   ;)    At least - if you happen to be an elephant.....

Comment: Both of those levels would be lethal if they were actually feasible BTW --- It takes about 10mA to stop a heartbeat....

Comment: There is plenty of good reference material on this: https://www.cdc.gov/niosh/docs/98-131/pdfs/98-131.pdf You don't appear to have done even a basic amount of research.

Comment: This question just does not make sence to me. As already stated, you can't have one without the other. It is often said "It's not the voltage that kills you, it's the current". The thing is, you simply can't have current without voltage (Ohm's law).
Combination of voltage and current may kill you then.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because asks about the danger of physically impossible scenarios and hence is inanswerable. Explaining Ohm's law is not on scope for an electrical engineering site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dangerous AC or DC](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/54978/dangerous-ac-or-dc)

Comment: You may want to review [this question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/2028) to better understand how current is drawn by a load rather than 'pushed' from a supply.

Comment: if you think that B can be deadly, then you better be very careful when putting batteries into your flashlight ... i mean, those can go as high as 1.5 V

Answer (score 1):

> Which one is more **dangerous** to human body among high voltage or
> current and their AC and DC versions?

Assuming the "1000 V & 1A" and "1 V and & 1000A" refers to the voltage and current that normally occurs in some electrical circuit, the 1000 V (at *up to* 1 A) is far more dangerous than the 1 V (at *up to* 1000 A) because the higher voltage can force more current through the human body.

[Ohm's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law) says resistance = voltage / current, so to push enough current through the body to harm you at 1V the resistance has to be very low - much lower than normal skin resistance. 1V applied directly to the heart might be enough, but that is unlikely to occur by accident.

AC is more dangerous than DC because the peak voltage is higher (which causes higher peak current that breaks down skin resistance more) and it reverses polarity regularly giving the effect of multiple shocks. The heart is particularly sensitive to mains frequency AC because it will try to follow the frequency and go into fibrillation.

Other parts of the body can handle a lot more current, but will be cooked or burned by high current (I still have a hole in my thumb where 240 VAC went through my hand 40 years ago). RF frequency AC doesn't have the same 'shocking' effect, but causes burns that are slow to heal.

Another danger of electric shock is uncontrolled muscle spasms. AC gives continuous shocks that may prevent the victim from letting go, whereas DC only shocks at the moment of contact. Muscle spasms can tear ligaments and tendons, and might cause a dangerous accident such as falling off a ladder or violently hitting something.

However "1 V & 1000 A" DC could still be dangerous if you shorted it out with a metallic object (ring, screwdriver etc.) that vaporized due to the high current flow and splattered molten metal over you. That is why we use insulated tools and wear eye protection even when working on extra low voltage high current circuits.

Comment: thanks....this is the kind of explanation I'm looking for.

Comment: when working with the household circuits, many times we get in direct contact with the wires but didn't get that much shock although we get the mild shock.
What are the reasons behind that?

Comment: Usually its because the path to ground or neutral has very high resistance, or you only touched the neutral wire (which is connected to ground). When I was a trainee technician the boss told me to remove a light switch from a 'dead' circuit. I handled the bare wires without getting a shock because I was wearing plastic soled shoes and standing on a lino floor. Then my hand brushed against the earthed conduit and pow! Turns out the circuit was live, but the bulb had been removed so there was no voltage between the wires (lesson #1, never trust what the boss tells you!).

Answer (score 0):

A domestic power supply voltage (110 or 230 V), 50 or 60 Hz alternating current (AC) through the chest for a fraction of a second may induce ventricular fibrillation at currents as low as 30 milliamperes (mA). With direct current (DC), 300 to 500 mA is required.

[Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_injury#:%7E:text=A%20domestic%20power%20supply%20voltage,to%20500%20mA%20is%20required.)

It's current that kills, not voltage; the amount of current present is going to depend on both voltage and resistance.

Comment: Isn't it a bit overkill to say "it's current that kills"? There will be no current without voltage.

Comment: ok, If anyone touched both terminals of home inverter (powerback up) battery, one by each hand. Then it will not be dangerous as it has only 12V ?

Comment: The 'debate' about whether current or voltage kills is like asking whether a gun or bullet kills. The bullet does very little without first having been propelled by a gun; conversely, the gun doesn't cause damage by itself.